# How do I edit multiple files in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, glob

I was trying to edit alot of images at the same time using pil and python it shows me this error:

[image: list object has no attribute read]

my code so far is below

```py
import glob
import PIL
from PIL import Image

image = glob.glob('./*.png')

img = Image.open(image)
img.putalpha(127)
img.save("")
```

Comment: Try using multi thread (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this:

```
import glob
import PIL
from PIL import Image

for i in glob.glob('./*.png'):
    img = Image.open(i)
    img.putalpha(127)
    img.save("")
```

Comment: I didn't know that for loops exists in python I am now a c developer using for loops all the time, thank you for making my journey smooth even if I was asking the stupidest questions back then :D

Comment: also don't ask how I became a C developer in a few months